# $scope is undefined outside of $http.get()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular code:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[]).
controller('ProductController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Product = {};
    $scope.categoryList = null;
    $scope.LoadCategory = function () {

        $scope.a = 'sss';

        $http.get('/Product/GetAllCategory/')
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data.success == true)
            {
                console.log = (data.data);
                $scope.categoryList = data.data;

            }
            else {
                alert('aws');
            }

        })
        .error(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + ": " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown, 'Error!!!');
        })
    };
});
```

and I fetched data using $http.get() from this server side code

```
public JsonResult GetAllCategory()
{
    //List<tblCategory> categories = new List<tblCategory>();
    try
    {
        using (CurtainHomesDBEntities dc = new CurtainHomesDBEntities())
        {
            var categories = dc.tblCategory.Select(a => new { a.Id, a.CatagoryName }).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = categories, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex);
    }
}
```

I debugged using firebug. It fetched data from server side and inserted to `$scope.categoryList`. But after coming the debug outside of `if(data.success==true)`, `$scope.categoryList` is `undefined`.

What is the problem here? I could not find out.

Comment: can you explain what you mean: _after coming the debug outside of if(data.success==true) $scope.CategoryList be come undefined._? js case sensitive, so `$scope.CategoryList` and `$scope.categoryList` is different variables

Comment: Please don't use snippets fore code that isn't supposed to run in the question.

Comment: I recommend getting consistent with how you spell "category."  Your code will be more prone to error when you introduce variations like `a.CatagoryName`.

Comment: @Grundy: That doesn't throw a syntax error, actually. It's incorrect, indeed, though ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus yep :-) i already get it :-) but anyway rewrite console method - not good :-)

Comment: $scope.CategoryList was a spelling mistake. I updated it. :(

Comment: @Cerbrus when the debug point pass just $scope.categoryList = data.data it carries data got from server side. after that It becomes undefined and my view does not get the data

Comment: @NewazSharif, check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bEwt7mNgjOZNHiXjeOm2?p=preview) your code work fine, can you change it to reproduce your problem? of course if you not forget  call `LoadCategory`

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get('/Product/GetAllCategory/')` returns an `HttpPromise`.

I would use the following (from angularjs documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http))

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: OP use `success` callback from documentation

Comment: This isn't the problem in the OP's code. `.success` should work just fine.